# how to overcome CLOB run out of space - ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle9i

I have a scenario where I am appending string to a clob. The issue I have is that once the CLOB reaches a certain size if I try to append more to the clob I get a ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error. I assume that it is running out of size but I do not know how to overcome the problem (i.e. specify how to make the clob bigger).

Could someone please help me.

This is how i declare my CLOB...

```
LP_xml_result CLOB;

DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(
      lob_loc => LP_xml_result
    , cache   => true
    , dur     => dbms_lob.call
);

DBMS_LOB.OPEN(
      lob_loc    => LP_xml_result
    , open_mode  => DBMS_LOB.LOB_READWRITE
);
```

And then I insert into it like so....

```
PROCEDURE lob_append(i_string IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN

    dbms_lob.append(LP_xml_result,LP_LineFeed || i_string);
END lob_append;
```

thanks

Comment: does it get bigger than 4GB?

Comment: Since Oracle 11 a LOB can be max `(4 GB - 1) * DB_BLOCK_SIZE`, i.e. 8TB to 128TB. 4GB was the limit till Oracle 10

Comment: I checked the Oracle Docs and see two possible issues. When you open a LOB then you also have to close it. However, it is not mandatory to open/close a LOB - try it without. Instead of creating a TEMPORARY LOB try `LP_xml_result := EMPTY_CLOB()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `LP_LineFeed || i_string` it makes an implicit cast to `VARCHAR2`, there you have the limit of 32K.

Do it like this:

```
PROCEDURE lob_append(i_string IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN

    dbms_lob.append(LP_xml_result,LP_LineFeed);
    dbms_lob.append(LP_xml_result,i_string);
END lob_append;
```

Regarding your problem with printing to HTP, some time ago I hat the same issue, here is my solution:

```
chunkSize   CONSTANT INTEGER := 5000;
pos NUMBER;

BEGIN
IF LENGTH(CLOB_VAL) > chunkSize THEN
    LOOP
        Htp.prn(SUBSTR(CLOB_VAL, pos, chunkSize));
        pos := pos + chunkSize;
        EXIT WHEN pos > LENGTH(CLOB_VAL);
    END LOOP;
ELSE
    Htp.prn(CLOB_VAL);
END IF;
```

Comment: The scope of your temporary CLOB is `CALL`, did you try something else, e.g. `SESSION`?

Comment: thank you for your help. I actually found that it was related to me printing the clob out using htp.print. Apparently you can't write the whole contents of a clob at once if it exceeds a certain length. I got the clue from this website...http://ddoracle.blogspot.com.au/2006/11/print-clob-to-web.html. This solved my issue